# How come too many html tags in a single html file exists?

Tags: html

I came across an HTML file that has the source code containing the root html tag and a child html tag along with several other elements! How come would this be possible? Is this really correct? If yes, how browsers interpret this nature and render?

Comment: Can you post the code or a link to it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you see an html which contains an iframe ;)

An iframe contains another html page (and so a html, body block). Firebug shows you the html code as a single page embeding another page, so it maybe why you are confused

Comment: The iframe references another document. It wouldn't cause multiple HTML elements to appear in a single file.

Comment: yes I know that but there are two cases : the html code is bad or you are seeing a html code with an iframe (which reference another page) but as Firebug shows the html page of the referenced page directly in the same code source of the parent page, I was thinking you doesn't know what is an iframe ;)

Comment: Firebug shows it in the DOM viewer, but you won't see it in the source.

Comment: yes you're right, it was what I want to say but I was not precise enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

> How come would this be possible?

People make mistakes.

> Is this really correct?

No, it is an error.

> If yes, how browsers interpret this nature and render?

Browsers perform enormous amounts of error recovery as there are many error ridden documents on the WWW. The [HTML 5 specification describes how most recent browsers parse HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html), this includes some of the error recovery mechanisms.